# card.io card scan never completes

Tags: android, card.io

I am trying to use [card.io](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-Android-SDK) in my Android app to scan for cards and have implemented the following,

```
private void requestCardIOScan() {

    Intent scanIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), CardIOActivity.class);

    // customize these values to suit your needs.
    scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_REQUIRE_EXPIRY, true); // default: false
    scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_REQUIRE_CVV, false); // default: false
    scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_REQUIRE_POSTAL_CODE, false); // default: false
    scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_USE_PAYPAL_ACTIONBAR_ICON, false);
    scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_USE_CARDIO_LOGO, false);
    scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_HIDE_CARDIO_LOGO, true);
    scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_KEEP_APPLICATION_THEME, true);

    // MY_SCAN_REQUEST_CODE is arbitrary and is only used within this activity.
    startActivityForResult(scanIntent, 100);
}
```

However the card scan never seems to complete for me even after I get green bars all around the card (which I assume means that the card is properly detected). Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

BTW, think its worth mentioning that I was trying this with a Samsung S5 and the S6 Edge.

Comment: Both S5 and S6 scan cards successfully.  Are you sure you're using a card that can be scanned (embossed, raised digits)?  If you're unsure, try using an app with card.io already integrated (like Uber) to test your card.

Comment: Thanks. That was indeed the issue. Sadly 4 of my 5 cards were not detectable by card.io. The only one that worked was an old embossed card, and based on this will probably not be using it (as the camera permissions already scare users away and it would be even worse if that didnt work for them :) )

Comment: try this code http://stackoverflow.com/a/38178590/3496570

Answer (score 4):

FYI

Valid card image for card.io scanning, It's worked for me on ( 10-02-2018 )

[image]

This image is copied from the internet from the following url
https://cdn.moneycrashers.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/capital-one-secured-mastercard.jpg

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely due to the card not having embossed numbers, or not a pattern that they support. See the Issue tracker of cardIO. [cardIO Issue](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-Android-SDK/issues/55)

cardIO would able to detect this type of embossed card:
[image]

Would not deduct this type of cards:
[image]